# How to override parameter defined in interface method with richer type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, arguments, overriding, base-class

I have these:

```
public class TennisPlayer
{

}

public class RogerFederer : TennisPlayer
{

}

public class RafaelNadal : TennisPlayer
{

}
```

And then I have some classes with methods, like these:

```
public abstract class Manager
{
    protected abstract void ScheduleFriendlies(TennisPlayer player);
}

public class RafaelNadalManager : Manager
{
    public void ScheduleFriendlies(RafaelNadal rn)
    {
        //throw new NotClayException();
    }
}

public class RogerFedererManager : Manager
{
    public void ScheduleFriendlies(RogerFederer rf)
    {
        //throw new NotGrassException();
    }
}

//'RafaelNadalManager' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Manager.ScheduleFriendlies(TennisPlayer)'
```

The thing I'm trying to achieve is that I would want to have child classes of `Manager` but every such class will be tied to one player and hence the methods in those child classes (`Manager` classes) will be specific to that player. In other words `Roger` should have his own `ScheduleFriendlies` while `Rafael` should have his own.

**How do I go about this? Alternate designs would do, but keep in mind:**

**What I can alter**: The inheritances, its routes etc

**But do not have the luxury to**: Take off child manager classes and merge into one (in other words, I need `RogerFederer` and `RogerFedererManager` as separate classes).

**I tried this**:

```
public abstract class Manager
{
    protected abstract bool ScheduleFriendlies<T>(T player) where T : TennisPlayer;
}

public class RafaelNadalManager : Manager
{
    protected override bool ScheduleFriendlies<T>(T player)
    {
        //but how do I enforce the caller that only RafaelNadal object can be 
        //passed to this but not RogerFederer?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were close, but you need the class generic, not just the method:

```
public abstract class Manager<T> where T : TennisPlayer
{
    protected abstract bool ScheduleFriendlies(T player);
}
```

You could then use:

```
public class RafaelNadalManager : Manager<RafaelNadal>
{
     protected override bool ScheduleFriendlies(RafaelNadal player)
     {}
}
```

Comment: I almost did it in my code before your answer, yes I was there! :)